# Clear slash command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

At the beginning I would like to point out that I do not use the py-cord module only and only discord.py. I wanted to create a / clear command.The problem is when the application that has to return the feedback that successfully deleted n messages from the user xyz.

There is an error mentioning

> "await interaction.response.send_message (content = content, ephemeral
> = True)"

is an unknown interaction

All code slash command:

```
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
t = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@t.command(name="clear", description="Clear n messages specific user", guild=discord.Object(id=867851000286806016))
async def self(interaction: discord.Interaction, amount: int, member: discord.Member):
    channel = interaction.channel

    def check_author(m):
        return m.author.id == member.id
    await channel.purge(limit=amount, check=check_author)
    content = f"Successfully deleted {amount} messages from {member.name}"
    await interaction.response.send_message(content=content, ephemeral=True)
client.run(discord_TOKEN)
```

At the end, I wanted to point out that the bot removes the number of messages that were given. Only feedback from the bot application is missing.

I have the message: The application is not responding

Comment: You can defer the interaction before you delete any messages, then followup.

Comment: Defer is not completely needed, the solution is to swap interactions first send a reply from the bot and then delete the messages

Answer (score 0):

Use this. I hope that I can help you with it.

```py
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
t = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@t.command(name="clear", description="Clear n messages specific user", guild=discord.Object(id=867851000286806016))
async def self(ctx, interaction: discord.Interaction, amount: int, member: discord.Member):
    channel = interaction.channel

        def check_author(m):
            return m.author.id == member.id
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount, check=check_author)
        await ctx.send(f"Successfully deleted {amount} messages from {member.name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this command for my bot and it works.

```
@t.command(name="clear",description="Delete Messages automatically from the current channel")
async def cl(bot, number:int, member:discord.Member = None):
  channel = bot.channel
  if number > 50:
    number = 50
  def check_(m):
    return m.author == member
  if not member:
    await channel.purge(limit=number)
  else:
    await channel.purge(limit=number,check=check_)
  await bot.response.send_message(f"Deleted: {number}, from this channel.")
```